# How to implement licensing?

Tags: licensing

Is the following an acceptable way of doing program licensing?

A license file containing following informations:

- Magic identifier (to verifiy that it is a license file for the program)
- License id
- Customer id
- License create date
- License expire date (to check if it is expired)
- Last use date (to verify that the system time wasn't modified to an earlier time)
- Extra fields, e.g. unlocked features

The license is encrypted with an encrypted string containing the computer's mainboard id, CPU id and BIOS id.

The customer gets a license key, which is a random generated string which will be stored on a server.

A license file is obtained from the server using the license key and the encrypted computer id.

On program start, it will check for internet connection and checks the license online. (e.g. if it was revoked)

Comment: Sounds good to me.  What do you do about the folks who patch a JMP instruction into your executable to bypass all this?

Comment: One can probably not protect against everthing.. But I'm here for some suggestions to make it somehow more secure than this.

Comment: Why encrypt it with a hardware-locked key when you could simply encrypt it asymmetrically and just distribute the public key with your program? Beyond that, it looks like an acceptable licensing scheme.

Comment: I suggest that you compute the cost of designing, implementing, testing, documenting and fixing bugs in such a system vs the costs of purchasing an off-the-shelf licensing system from a vendor who specializes in such. Then compare both costs against the *actual costs* of users using the system off-license. Not the lost revenue; the actual *costs*.

Comment: @EricLippert: You've got a point, but it's not always about costs. Sometimes it's about learning.

Answer (score 3):

Your scheme seems quite complete.

Nevertheless I see several flaws:

1. The fact to add the last use date in the license file forces you to alter the file at each execution:

   - This requires the file to be in a shared place with R/W access for all the users.  If on Windows, make sure that it doesn't require admin privileges.
   - This immediately raises the question of concurrent use if the shared location is on a file server.  Do you foresee a licence for a certain number of users?
   - Finally, this mechanism bears the risk of getting the file corrupted in case of abrupt termination, which in turn will increase the complaints to your helpdesk organisation
2. I guess that for all these dates, you take into account GMT time in order not to experience problems with timezone changes and switch to daylight saving time (which could create a false positive for time alteration)
3. How will you handle customers who have acquired a license, but repair their PC or change equipment ?
4. As Robert told in the comments, it's easy to run the executable in debug mode, find the place where these check take place and monitor what happens (either to do a jump, or to access to unencrypted/encryption keys in memory.   I'd strongly advise that you add some timing in your startup code, that checks the time span required to arrive to you control routine, and if it's too long (debug mode) run something else than the normal check (distraction), and terminate with an unclear error message.

Comment: 1. Didn't thought of shared execution at all yet.. Good point. 2. Already had in mind the daylight saving, but good to point out for others. 3. Give the customer a way to deactive the old license online and acquire a new one. Another way is to revoke old one on server and grant a new one manually. 4. Time checking sounds good, but how to define the maximum allowed, testing it on some antique hardware to get some times on how long it could take?

Comment: @RaphaelH 4. The goal here is to avoid amateurs knowing to run the debuger step by step through the assembler code. SO there's an order of magnitude of difference. I guess it would take at least a couple of seconds to step trhough manually.  I think that even on slower machine you wouldn't need so much time to run through your license init code.

Comment: @Christophe: Licensing systems mitigate the "honest thief" problem; that is, a customer who wishes to pay for the system but uses it off-license accidentally. I see little point in designing systems to prevent genuine attacks; if the software is running on the user's machine, they own every byte in every process. You cannot even know that your software is running in a physical machine; it may be entirely emulated, in which case you cannot even trust the "hardware".

Comment: Christophe: That's true. Thanks for your input so far. @EricLippert: It is not about protecting it against every  possibility. Just enough that not any idiot can make a license generator..

Comment: @EricLippert You have of course good arguments.  I do not take position on automated license controls, I just try to provide some ideas. As you can see I'm worried about undue loss of a legitimate access (see 1.c and 3) because customers get quickly very upset with this.  And Raphael's approach seems rather light and acceptable if compared to the bloated license control platforms that are sometimes installed along with purchased software and that run and monitor permanently your machines, stealing from all the users their computing power.

Comment: @Christophe: Uh, that reminds me of something. In the late 90s there used to be a group which specialized in cracking the copy protection of a certain well-known audio production software. And they said in an interview that according to their analysis, up to 40% of CPU cycles are actually spent not doing useful work but purely on copy protection. For something as time-sensitive as real-time audio production, mixing, FX, etc. that is a truly ridiculous number. (Interestingly, the group suddenly vanished off the face of the earth, and rumour has it, they were hired by the very company that …

Comment: … produced the copy protection systems they were cracking. There definitely was a remarkable improvement in stability and performance shortly thereafter! Before that, the software was so famous for its instability that people were actually buying legitimate licenses but still running cracked versions, just to get rid of the incredibly crappy kernel driver that was part of the copy protection system and would often hang or crash the system.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag I wasn't aware of that story, but I've heard about this major who installed a rootkit on its music CD.  Personnally I managed to get away from all the products that install such bloatware. But I've nothing against nice software that does some discrete basic license controls like Raphael intends to do.  Most of them run for a limited time in "unregistered mode" , which can save the week-end if you screw up, have to reinstall and there are issues with reactivating license

Comment: @Christophe: it is always important to keep your users in mind. I am old enough to have lived through the era when every vendor had their own parallel port dongle, and you would have so many of them attached to the back of your PC that their weight alone could damage your motherboard if you didn't properly support them. In professional audio, PCs are carefully tuned for performance, which includes disabling safety features such as firewalls, NX, and so on, and disabling automatic updates. Naturally, such a PC **must not** be connected to the Internet. (Plus, there's usually no Internet on …

Comment: … stage anyway.) And if you use a laptop on stage as a musical instrument, you don't want to have dongles protruding out the sides, either, a stage is a rough enough place as it is, you don't have to deliberately attach traps to your laptop :-D And yet, many professional audio software requires either Internet access, a dongle, or both, for copy protection / license enforcement.